# PHP: 2 Domain names, 1 session

Tags: php, session, heroku

I've got a site hosted with Heroku. Heroku assigns my site a domain name of `someName.herokuapp.com`. I've got a custom domain name `www.someName.com` which points to `someName.herokuapp.com`. For consistency purposes in my config file I have a variable:

```
$ServerPath = "somename.herokuapp.com/";
```

That way when I need to reference a some file I could just go `$ServerPath.$fileName`

Here's the problem. When the user logs in from `www.somename.com` a session is created on the server. However if at any time the user clicks some link which is tied to `$ServerPath` the user is redirected to `somename.herokuapp.com` and on THAT domain the session seems to be non-existant and the user is logged out.

Is there any way to keep my $ServerPath var as `someName.herokuapp.com` and have the session to be open on both `www.someName.com` and `someName.herokuapp.com`?

Comment: Sessions are tied to cookies, and cookies don't go across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the expected behavior for (session) cookies. You request a certain domain and the browser will send it's cookies for that domain (i.e. www.somename.com). Now you click a link: somename.herokuapp.com. The browser does not send ANY cookie from www.somename.com

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. automaticly redirect somename.herokuapp.com to www.somename.com (or visa versa), so everything is always on the same (sub)domain.
2. Create a session-transfer via the URL. You could use `session.use-trans-sid` or anything similar. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid. This approach also has downsides.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.someName.com [R=301,L]
```

He will be redirected from url's other than http://www.someName.com